Save to a console.log() variable
I'm starting with javascript now.
I'm looking for a tip or guidance as I can't seem to get any further.
Do I need to save the result of line 70 of console.log(html) in a variable (const, let or var)?
Any tips on doing this? I tried arguments and return in the runRtfjs function, but it didn't work.
I need to save it in a variable to later display it in HTML.
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const {JSDOM} = jsdom;

const filertf =
    `{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\deflang1033{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
    {\\*\\generator Msftedit 5.41.21.2510;}\\viewkind4\\uc1\\pard\\sa200\\sl276\\slmult1\\lang9\\f0\\fs22 This \\fs44 is \\fs22 a \\b simple \\ul one \\i paragraph \\ulnone\\b0 document\\i0 .\\par
    }`;

function stringToArrayBuffer(string) {
    const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(string.length);
    const bufferView = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        bufferView[i] = string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buffer;
}

function runRtfjs(rtf, callback, errorCallback) {
    const virtualConsole = new jsdom.VirtualConsole();
    virtualConsole.sendTo(console);

    new JSDOM(`
    <script src="./node_modules/rtf.js/dist/WMFJS.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="./node_modules/rtf.js/dist/EMFJS.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="./node_modules/rtf.js/dist/RTFJS.bundle.js"></script>

    <script>
        RTFJS.loggingEnabled(false);
        WMFJS.loggingEnabled(false);
        EMFJS.loggingEnabled(false);

        try {
            const doc = new RTFJS.Document(rtfFile);

            const meta = doc.metadata();
            doc.render().then(function(htmlElements) {
                const div = document.createElement("div");
                div.append(...htmlElements);

                window.done(meta, div.innerHTML);
            }).catch(error => window.onerror(error))
        } catch (error){
            window.onerror(error)
        }
    </script>
    `, {
        resources: "usable",
        runScripts: "dangerously",
        url: "file://" + __dirname + "/",
        virtualConsole,
        beforeParse(window) {
            window.rtfFile = stringToArrayBuffer(rtf);
            window.done = function (meta, html) {
                callback(meta, html);
            };
            window.onerror = function (error) {
                errorCallback(error);
            };
        }
    });
};


runRtfjs(
    filertf,
    (meta, html) => {
        //console.log("Meta:");
        //console.log(meta);
        //console.log("Html:");
        console.log(html);
    },
    error => console.error(error)
    );

I tried arguments and return in the runRtfjs function, but it didn't work.

It's already in a variable, it's named html. I think your problem is that you don't yet understand asynchronicity.

Does this answer your question? How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?

Declear a variable outside the scope of the function and assign the value to it.
If it's to be re-used in the same scope you can use let instead of var
var htmlData;
runRtfjs(
  filertf,
  (meta, html) => {
       htmlData = html;
       console.log(html);
       
  },
      error => console.error(error)
  );


var returns as undefined var htmlData; runRtfjs(   filertf,   (meta, html) => {         htmlData = html;   },       error => console.error(error)   ); console.log(htmlData)

That's because you access the variable before your function even wrote to it. Any code that uses the result must be within the callback, like your console.log was originally, so it can run once your function is done and not immediately.

Declare a variable outside the function to hold the result.
Modify the runRtfjs function to set the variable with the HTML content.
Use the variable after the function has executed.
